# Question with MathJaX tag

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, mathjax

In different occasions when I see a question tagged `MathJaX` I think many times if I should answer it or not. Generally on the `TeX.SE.` site the questions marked with this tag are off-topic.

> Which are the criteria, or the indications, or the signals that help me to understand if I can answer or not?

Comment: if you can answer it using latex, then it's usually reasonable to do so, if it's just about the javascipt setup, or the question is "this works in latex but not in mathjax", then it's probably not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand your concept, but I hope for me to apply it correctly. And...always thank you.